# How to read the Numpy documentation

Tags: numpy

For example:

```
random.randint(low, high=None, size=None, dtype='l')

>>> np.random.randint(2, size=10)
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

The parameters are low, high, size, dtype, but then what's the parameter of the '2' in the function call? It doesn't correspond to any parameter?

Comment: `then results are from [0, `low`)`.  The numbers are drawn from [0,1], or [0,2).  The parameters are explained in more detail further down the docs.

Comment: shouldn't it be low=2 or high=2? otherwise, how does it match the exact parameter name (high or low)?

Comment: Don't get focus on the names.  Sometimes the names don't adequately express the variations of interpretation.  Think for example of the parameters for `range` or `arange`.  `range(high)`, `range(low, high)`, `range(low, high, step)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'2' corresponds to the low parameter.

You don't need to specify 'low' because its a positional argument.

In general, random.randint generates number between [low,high). But, if high=None, then it generates number between [0,low)

Hence you get integers between 0 and 2(excluded)

Comment: For positional argument, if you don't specify the argument name, the '2' automatically matches with the first argument 'low'?

Comment: yes. As you can see low is positional arguemnt whereas high,size,dtype are keyword arguemnts`numpy.random.randint(low, high=None, size=None, dtype='l')`

If you found it helpful, please upvote and verify. Thanks!

Comment: @marlon They are all positional arguments, but some have defaults. `numpy.random.randint(2,None,10)` would work too.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, if I want to use '2' to be associated with "high", then I have to specifically use randint(high=2), otherwise, it doesn't know which argument it belongs to, because in this case, only one parameter is passed in, while the function signature defines 3 arguments. when randint(2) is used, it will regard '2' as the first argument. Is that right?

Comment: @marlon since low doesn’t have a default, it is required, so can’t just specify high.